# Requested module experienced an error while loading

Tags: lua, roblox

Roblox says, Requested module experienced an error while loading on the line `local combatModule = require(script.Combat)` . Can some one please help me fix this question?

```
Punching.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, currentAttack)
    local char = player.Character
    local Stand = char:FindFirstChild("Stand")
    local weld = Stand.HumanoidRootPart:FindFirstChild("Weld")
    
    local combatModule = require(script.Combat) 
     
    Stand.HumanoidRootPart.Massless = true
    
    if currentAttack == 1 then
        combatModule.Main(weld, TweenService, Stand, script.Animations.RightPunch, char, currentAttack)
    elseif currentAttack == 2 then
        combatModule.Main(weld, TweenService, Stand, script.Animations.LeftPunch, char, currentAttack)
    elseif currentAttack == 3 then
        combatModule.Main(weld, TweenService, Stand, script.Animations.Smash, char, currentAttack)
        
    end
end)
```

Comment: The error is in the `script.Combat` module, not here. You need to share that code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.